# getting key error on running trackpy on background subtracted video

Tags: opencv, background-subtraction, trackpy

I am new to python programing.
I am using background subtraction on avi video file followed by tracking the cells in image using trackpy

When i run the code it gives the error:
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'frame'

my code is

```
import cv2
import trackpy as tp



cap = cv2.VideoCapture('0.3_1_23.64fps.avi')
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN()

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == 1:
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
        #cv2.imshow('fgmask',fgmask)
        #k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
        #if k == 27:
        #   break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

f = tp.locate(fgmask, 25, invert=False, minmass= 30)
#tp.annotate(f, fgmask)
t = tp.link(f, 5, memory=5)
```

I am using background subtraction on avi video file followed by tracking the cells in image using trackpy

Answer (score 0):

KeyError indicates that the requested key of the key/value pair the dictionary uses cannot be found/does not exist. It may be that you are passing malformed data into your package's functions. I don't know the specifics of cv2 or trackpy, but make sure that the arguments for the functions you're using from them are getting proper data.

Also take note of the 4 commented out lines in the middle of the code:

```py
#cv2.imshow('fgmask',fgmask)
#k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
#if k == 27:
#   break
```

If none of this helps, you can try looking into the package's files and making sure they're working correctly. You can try re-downloading them, but this is unlikely to be the answer.

Comment: these  Commented out lines corresponds to view video after background subtraction process and is working correctly;
code works fine until last line is executed.

i would also like to point out that when i am not using if else statement in loop it does show error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_mat.empty() in function 'cv::RNG::fill'